# Why does normalize-space() not strip all spaces?

Tags: xml, xslt, removing-whitespace

I wrote a little XSLT where I added `normalize-space()` function to strip unnecessary spaces:

http://xsltransform.net/bnnZWM

```
<xsl:template match="page/pageFunctionResult/*/text()">
   <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The XSLT itself works, except that some spaces are not normalized:

```
<category> TEST </category>
```

I don't understand why `normalize-space()` can't remove these spaces.

Comment: Do you also have a [`<xsl:strip-space elements="xsl:*"/>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip)?

Comment: Not, but I added: http://xsltransform.net/bnnZWM/1 -> no change.

Comment: Characters around `TEST` doesn't look like whitespace, in the link you posted. This one is copy-pasted from yours, and it gets normalized as expected : http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38ZP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [normalize-space()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) function strips [***whitespace***](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-S):

> ```
> [3]       S      ::=      (#x20 | #x9 | #xD | #xA)+
> ```

The characters surrounding `TEXT` in your linked example are *not* one of these characters (as @har07 points out in the comments).  Per @michael.hor257k's [clever use of `string-to-codepoints()`](http://xsltransform.net/bnnZWM/3),

```
<xsl:template match="page/pageFunctionResult[1]/category[1]">
  <xsl:value-of select="string-to-codepoints(substring(., 1, 1))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

we can see that they are [NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) characters (#xA0), aka `&nbsp;`.

To remove `&nbsp;`, you'll need something more than `normalize-space()`....

### XSLT 1.0

[See @michael.hor257k's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35676601/290085)  (+1)

### XSLT 2.0

If you want to cover `&nbsp;` along with other types of whitespace characters, use `replace()` with a [category escape](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-ccescat) ahead of `normalize-space()`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(replace(., '\p{Z}', ' '))"/>
```

Comment: Got it. Is there any function like normalize-space(), but for NBSP characters?

Comment: @Adrian You could `translate` them to regular spaces before applying `normalize-space()`.

Answer (score 6):

As noted in comments, the characters are really NON-BREAKING SPACE characters (#160). To handle them as regular spaces, use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(., '&#160;', ' '))"/>
```